# AngularJS (1.3.x) Port issue when deployed heroku

Tags: angularjs, heroku

I have one issue when I deployed the angularJS application on Heroku. I am not getting port. Because Heroku changes the port on every refresh

I want to access this port in angularJS dynamically. How I can achieve this?

Like in Nodejs we are using `process.env.PORT`

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved
I added URL of Heroku and set port is 80  for both node js and angular js